# Modify Bamboo variable via batch file

Tags: variables, bamboo

I'm trying to set a bamboo global variable in a script contained in a batch file. Here is the batch file:

```
@echo off
echo Initial Date: %bamboo_releaseDate%

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
set mydate=%year%%month%%day%
echo %mydate:~2,6%

set bamboo_releaseDate=%mydate:~2,6%
echo Set up date: %bamboo_releaseDate%
```

And here is my output:

```
Initial Date: 140617
140619
Set up date: 140619
```

However, as soon as the script is run, Bamboo puts back the old value. Is there a way to avoid that? How would you suggest to do it?

My goal is to have one folder per nightly build with the date in the name of the folder. I use therefore the standard 'Artifact download' from Bamboo and give some parameters for the name of the containing folder.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Bamboo, you could use ${system.} to store values for later use. More details here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Bamboo+variables

Is there a reason you want to over-write the bamboo.releasedate value? If you have builds that start on the evening and finish in the morning, you could pass an artifact to each successive build to get the release date. However, if you can run all your builds on the same day, change the start time and reset your batch file to build its own date and use that going forward (each time the build runs, it would regenerate the build date).